# Why do I get this error? AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_cards'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
class Deck:
    suits = ["H", "D", "C", "S"]
    values = [str(i) for i in range(2, 11)] + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.fill_deck()

    def fill_deck(self):
        for suit in Deck.suits:
            for value in Deck.values:
                card = value + suit
                self.cards.append(card)

    def copy(self):
        new_deck = Deck()
        new_deck = self.cards[:]
        return new_deck

    def get_cards(self):
        return self.cards[:]

deck1 = Deck()
deck2 = deck1.copy()
deck1.get_cards()
deck2.get_cards()
```

`new_deck = self.cards[:]` is where the error is occurring but I don't understand why. If I change `new_deck` to something else, it  will work, but I don't understand why...

Comment: First of all, the code works fine even though you overwrite `new_deck` in the `copy()` method. Second, if it fails for you - please provide traceback.

Comment: Hint: what does `Deck.copy()` return? What type? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @AGNGazer Huh? It fails at `deck2.get_cards()`. Did you try it? Maybe you missed the last line when copy-pasting.

Comment: @wjandrea Indeed, I missed last line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line in your `copy` function:

```
new_deck = self.cards[:]
```

It replaces the `Deck` object you created on the prior line with a copy of a list.  So now your `copy` function is returning a `list` instead of a `Deck`.  Probably what you wanted was:

```
new_deck.cards = self.cards[:]
```

Comment: I see, but what does new_deck.cards = self.cards[ : ] do? If I return new_deck, it will return the new deck I made, but it wont be a copy of the original deck right?

Comment: @kevinespina `self.cards[:]` will make a *slice* of the list, and with beginning and ending left blank it will copy the entire list.